# Shift the business month end date by different number of month in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a Date column in datetime64 and a column Month columns with different integers in float.

```
Date          Month    New_BDate
2020-06-30    0        2020-06-30
2020-06-30    -1       2020-05-29
2020-06-30    -2       2020-04-30
2020-06-30    -3       2020-03-31
2020-05-29    0        2020-05-29
2020-05-29    -1       2020-04-30
```

```
import pandas as pd
df['New_BDate'] = df['Date'] + df['shift'].map(pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthEnd())
```

Why do I get the below error and how should I solve it? or is there a better alternative?
*** AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'year'

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are couple of way's,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df['New_BDate'] = (
    df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date))
        .apply(lambda x: x['Date'] + np.timedelta64(x['Month'], 'M'), axis=1)
)
```

or

```
df['New_BDate'] = (
    df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date))
        .apply(lambda x: x['Date'] + pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessMonthEnd(x['Month']), axis=1)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

df['New_BDate'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Date'] + relativedelta(months=x['Month']), axis=1)
```